# where can I get driver for dell latitude d530 WIndows XP

Tags: windows-xp, dell-latitude, broadcom

I have a Dell Latitude D530, with Windows XP Professional SP3 installed, on which I can't get the Ethernet Controller working.

The wireless network connection works fine. This particular machine dual boots into either Linux or XP. When I boot into Linux, the wired network connection works fine, so the hardware & bios settings must be ok.

Looking in the XP Device Manager window,

[image: Device Manager screenshot]

I see that the 'Device Instance Id' is:

```
PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_1673&SUBSYS_02001028&REV_02\4&1E93A591&0&00E5
```

`14E4` identifies the controller as a Broadcom, and looking at their

[Broadcom list of devices](https://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet-nic)

list of devices, `DEV_1673` indicates a *BCM5755M NetXtreme Desktop/Mobile*.

However, I can't get a driver to successfully install. Nearest I can find is the Broadcom download `win_b57_32-17.2.0.2.zip`, but unzipping that & attempting to install via the XP Hardware Update Wizard fails with the wizard saying that it 'cannot find the necessary software'.

Either putting the service tag into Dell's support site, or browsing the ftp version, doesn't lead to anything, as far as I can tell, that works for XP.

From the Dell site, I've tried:

Broadcom_57XX-Gigabit-Integr_A00_R248117.exe
and
Broadcom_57XX-Gigabit-Integr_A00_R248124.exe

the latter, telling me once installed, that no active Broadcom adapters can be detected.

Does anyone know what the correct driver might be & where I can get a copy?

Or, is it possible that I do have the right driver but some other system conflict or misconfiguration is preventing that it from recognizing the hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! For anyone with the same issue:

The driver from the Dell site, in particular
 Broadcom_57XX-Gigabit-Integr_A00_R248117.exe 
does work.

Invoking the exe unpacks a number of files & then automatically launches an installation procedure. However, the installation procedure it launches seems to be the wrong one for my machine. If I stop it, navigate to the location where the files were unpacked, find the xp32 directory and then install the driver using Device Manager with that directory as its file source, it works.

Thanks to Twisty & Mike

Answer (score 2):

Dell still has Windows XP drivers available for the Latitude D530 model line, including several for the **Broadcom 57XX Gigabit Integrated Controller**. They're available [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/latitude-d530/drivers).

> Either putting the service tag into Dell's support site, or browsing the ftp version, doesn't lead to anything, as far as I can see, for xp.

If you have trouble finding drivers on Dell's support site by service tag, start at their support homepage and browse for the drivers *by model number*. This ensures you'll see *all* of the drivers available for a specific model instead of a filtered list.

Comment: Thanks Twisty. I've tried a couple of what seem to be the correct drivers from Dell, but neither work. I've updated my question accordingly. Is it possible that I do have the right driver but some other system conflict or misconfiguration is preventing that it from recognizing the hardware?

Answer (score -1):

First of all the Dell support site for your computer is : http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/latitude-d530/drivers
(Scroll down a bit to the "View all available updates for Windows XP" section.)

After googling the device ID, I found this ("http://download.driverguide.com/driver/Broadcom+NetXtreme+57xx+Gigabit+Controller/Gigabyte+Technology/d1673327.html" web site, you can try the driver that is provided there, it says that yours is supported

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've just been looking on the official Dell & Broadcom sites, ignoring all the other hits that come up when googling for the correct driver. My fear is that installing something from any place other than the official source is a security/malware risk. Opinions re driverguide at https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/driverguide.com seem divided. Regarding the download from Dell, Broadcom_57XX-Gigabit-Integr_A00_R248117.exe, I've tried it without success.

Comment: Yuck; Third-Party driver website, wouldn't trust that, with a 10-foot pole